# Using FXRegistry to store persistent data in FXRuby

Tags: ruby, wxruby, fxruby

I'm using FXRegistry to store the username and password, so that I can authenticate with my web service. When a user logs in, the username and password get written to the FXRegistry, and everything *seems* great. But when I exit out of the application and run it again, it doesn't seem to be able to ready from FXRegistry. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code,

```
regis = FXRegistry.new(APP_KEY, VENDOR_KEY)
regis.writeStringEntry("USER_CACHE", "username", usrTextField.text)
regis.writeStringEntry("USER_CACHE", "password", pwdTextField.text)
```

And here's how I read from it,

```
regis.readStringEntry("USER_CACHE", "username")
regis.readStringEntry("USER_CACHE", "password")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally found out why my perfectly looking code didn't work. It all had to do with the proper way I exited my app. I was using the normal "exit" command to exit out, and it **clearly** says in the [FXRegistry](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox/FXRegistry#write-instance_method) documentation that, "*The registry is read when FXApp::init() is called, and written back to the system when FXApp::exit() is called.*"

So for those of us who don't know how to do that, here's how to do that,

```
getApp().exit(0)
```

An example at [fxruby.org](http://www.fxruby.org/examples/imageviewer.rb) actually uses FXRegistry to store app data.